# Reactive graph dependent on multiple inputs

Tags: shiny

I have a reactive graph that takes in multiple inputs but it is dependent on all those inputs. Is there a way that the graph can take all the inputs but it isn't dependent on them all. For example if the user selects one drop down the graph will update and not need any of the other inputs but if the user adds a second input the graph will update with the 2nd input but not need the 3rd unless it is selected. Also if what the user has selected is null it won't change the graph.

UI:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Human Trafficking"),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            selectInput("Source", "Choose a Data Source: ", choices = sort(unique(ngo$Data.Provided.By)), selected = NULL,
                        multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
            dateInput("startdate", "Start Date:", value = "2009-01-01", format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                      min = "2009-01-01", max = "2019-08-26"),

            dateInput("enddate", "End Date:", value = "2019-08-27", format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                      min = "2009-01-02", max = "2019-08-27"),
            selectInput("Nationality", "Select a nation: ", choices = sort(unique(ngo$Victim.Nationality))),
            actionButton("button", "Apply")
        )
    ),

    dashboardBody(

        fluidRow(
            box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE,
                selectInput("traffickingType", "Choose a trafficking type: ", choices = sort(unique(ngo$Trafficking.Type)), selected = NULL,
                            multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
            ),
            box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE,
                selectInput("traffickingSubType", "Choose a trafficking sub type: ", choices = sort(unique(ngo$Trafficking.Sub.Type)), selected = NULL,
                            multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
            ),
            box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE,
                selectInput("gender", "Choose a gender: ", choices = sort(unique(ngo$Victim.Gender)), selected = NULL,
                            multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
            )
        ),
        fluidRow(     
            box(width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                title = "Trafficking Type",
                plotlyOutput("coolplot", width = '750px', height = '600px')
            ),

            box(width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                title = "Trafficking Sub-Type",
                plotlyOutput("Sub", width = '750px', height = '600px')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$coolplot <- renderPlotly({
        ngo <-
            ngo %>%
            filter(Victim.Nationality %in% input$Nationality,
                   Victim.Gender %in% input$gender,
                   Trafficking.Type %in% input$traffickingType,
                   Trafficking.Sub.Type %in% input$traffickingSubType,
                   Data.Provided.By %in% input$Source
            ) %>%

            plot_ly(labels = ~Trafficking.Type, type = "pie")
    })
}
```

I want to be able to allow the user to select one input and it will update graph and the more they add the graph will keep updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the neatest but what about separating the filtering as below:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$coolplot <- renderPlotly({
        req(c(input$gender, input$traffickingType, input$traffickingSubType))

        if(!is.null(input$Nationality)) {
            ngo <- ngo %>% filter(Victim.Nationality %in% input$Nationality)
        }
        if(!is.null(input$gender)) {
            ngo <- ngo %>% filter(Victim.Gender %in% input$gender)
        }
        if(!is.null(input$traffickingType)) {
            ngo <- ngo %>% filter(Trafficking.Type %in% input$traffickingType)
        }
        if(!is.null(input$traffickingSubType)) {
            ngo <- ngo %>% filter(Trafficking.Sub.Type %in% input$traffickingSubType)
        }
        if(!is.null(input$Source)) {
            ngo <- ngo %>% filter(Data.Provided.By %in% input$Source)
        }

        plot_ly(ngo, labels = ~Trafficking.Type, type = "pie")
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Update**

based on comment below.

I added `req(c(input$gender, input$traffickingType, input$traffickingSubType))`.

I left out `input$Nationality` as that equals "A" on startup and `input$Source` I assumed but you can add `input$source` to the vector `c(...)` above if you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, Just one problem though. When I first open the shiny app the pie chart automatically creates with all inputs in it, how do I get it so that it wont display until the user selects an input?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!!